# Google Calendar API and API Key issues

Tags: javascript, api, google-calendar-api

OK.
So I am building a simple app for a friend. The biggest requirement for this app is that he wants a user to be able to go to his site and create an event on his google calendar. I have let him know that this calendar will have to be made public and he is fine with that. I created an API Key with google and the first call against the API with the API Key to get calendar events for a given day works fine. The second request, a post, returns :

err(401)"API keys are not supported by this API. Expected OAuth2 access token or other authentication credentials that assert a principal."

It doesn't make sense that his website would be an OAuth app because that would require the user have a gmail account.

There has got to be some kind of way to make this work ...

Thanks Everyone

I just want to make a post request to Google Calendar API using an API Key.

Answer (score 0):

API keys only give read access.  If you want write access you need the permission of the owner of the calendar

options

1. Create a google workspace account and use a service account with domain wide deligation
2. use Oauth2 have your friend auth it once store the refresh token and use the refresh token to request a new access token when ever you want to write to the calendar

neither option will work with client side JavaScript switch to a server side programming language

Comment: Possible to store refresh token in .env, run useEffect to exchange for access token, then make the api call?

Comment: yes to the env var I have no idea what useEffect is.   Yes  its a http post call to the identity server to get a new access token

Comment: found a workaround for front end. I can use Calendly and give it OAuth access to the google calendar and then embed a Calendly widget in the page. Thanks for the help tho @DalmTo

Comment: I'm not sure I would want to give a third party system access to my calendar but if it works for you that's great